# Do we need a Partitioner?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

In a Hadoop cluster with 10 terabytes of data and 30 nodes, do we need a partitioner?
 If yes, why? Please support with an example scenario as to, When do we need to implement a custom partitioner?

Comment: It is not a matter of data size. It is a matter of what you want to do with the data.

Comment: I have understood that the default number of reducers is 1 which means unless specified we will get single output file. 
If we want separate files for specific keys, we shall have to implement a custom partitioner (where number of partitions == number of reducers). And I will also have to increase reducers count in MR program? 

Did I get it Right?

Comment: Not really. In your MR program you `define` the number of reducers (say `x`). Then, using this number in your partitioner, you decide in which one of the `x` reducers, a specific map output pair will go. See the answer of @Jasper for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioner controls the partitioning of the keys of the intermediate map-outputs. 
Partitioner decides what map-output-keys are sent to what reducers.

Default is HashPartitioner

Eg:
Map output Key/Val: [A,1], [A,3], [B,5], [B,1], [C,9]

With default Partitioner - assuming there are 3 Reducers:
Reducer 1 will get: [A,1], [A,3]
Reducer 2 will get: [B,5], [B,1]
Reducer C will get: [C,9]

So all the data in a single partition gets executed by a single reducer. If number of reducers are less (say two above) - [C,9] will also go to Reducer 1 or 2 (Partition modulo behavior takes care of this).

Custom Partitioner is used to change this default behavior.
For eg: You can decide that key/values are sent to reducers as follows:
Reducer 1 shud get: [A,1], [B,5], [C,9]
Reducer 2 shud get: [B,1], [A,3]

There are many reasons why you would want to do this. 
For eg: 
- Reducer processing logic is based on grouping keys not based keys(hashes being same) - but something custom to you, so u want to group such keys together.
- Reducers create their own output files (one each). So if u want output files such that it contains data relating to certain keys.

Comment: So, yes, you always need a partitioner, but you don't always have to write a custom one.